# One block should overlap the two adjacent CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I need "div2" to overlap/cover its two adjacent block. I can do it with "div1", but I cannot do it with "div3". Someone know how to do it? Please see my code below with what I have a problem. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child_1">Some div1</div>
  <div class="child_2">Some div2</div>
  <div class="child_3">Some div3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #eef;
  height: 110px;
  width: 620px;
  margin: 20px
}

.child_1 {
  position: static;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  background:yellow;
}

.child_2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:-30px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  background:;
  left:-30px;
  top:-10px;
}

.child_3 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  background:yellow;
  left:-30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.child_3` needs to have `left:-60px;` in order to overlap `.child_2`

you have to add the -30px from `.child_2`to `child_3`, so -30px -30px = -60px

ADDITION: To really get child_2 to COVER child_3, assing `z-index:1` to `child_2`:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #eef;
  height: 110px;
  width: 620px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.child_1 {
  position: static;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  background:yellow;
}

.child_2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:-30px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  background:;
  left:-30px;
  top:-10px;
  z-index:1;
}

.child_3 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  background:yellow;
  left:-60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child_1">Some div1</div>
  <div class="child_2">Some div2</div>
  <div class="child_3">Some div3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it does not work ... I think this problem with position, but I don't know where exactly

Comment: try to change their `display` parameter to `block`

Comment: please note the addition to my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the negative left value on `child3`, and you need you use `z-index` to position `child2` on top

In below sample I simplified your code a little.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #eef;
  height: 110px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

.child.nr1 {
  background:yellow;
  margin-right: -60px;
}
.child.nr3 {
  background:yellow;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
.child.nr2 {
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child nr1">Some div1</div>
  <div class="child nr2">Some div2</div>
  <div class="child nr3">Some div3</div>
</div>
```