# Stacking some images

Tags: html, css

On my code I am trying to be able to stack images like

[image]

Where there are 2 images behind and one on top.

I have tried using floats and z-index

> **Question** how can I get it so my images are like in the above example?

**WORKING [DEMO](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/RoLMyB)** <-- Updated with working solution

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-12">
<img data-src="holder.js/50px320?theme=social" class="img-thumbnail img-1">
<img data-src="holder.js/50px320?theme=lava" class="img-thumbnail img-2">
<img data-src="holder.js/50px320?theme=grey" class="img-thumbnail img-3">
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-1 {
   z-index: 2;
   float: none;
   clear: both;
}

.img-2 {
   float: left; 
   z-index: 1;
}

.img-3 {
   float: right; 
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: So which of the 3 examples do you want to replicate?

Comment: similar question + answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40565524/5641669

Comment: `z-index` only works on positioned elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```css
.img-1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
   z-index: -1;
}

.img-2 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.img-3 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.4/holder.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <img data-src="holder.js/50px320?theme=social" class="img-thumbnail img-1">
      <img data-src="holder.js/50px320?theme=lava" class="img-thumbnail img-2">
      <img data-src="holder.js/50px320?theme=grey" class="img-thumbnail img-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of your floats and clears so that you can use the [position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) property. Set the container to relative positioning and set the images to absolute positioning.

```css
.container {
  postion: relative;
}
.img-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.img-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.img-3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60%;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.4/holder.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <img data-src="holder.js/50px320?theme=social" class="img-thumbnail img-1">
      <img data-src="holder.js/50px320?theme=lava" class="img-thumbnail img-2">
      <img data-src="holder.js/50px320?theme=grey" class="img-thumbnail img-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).