# 3 Image layout - Center image larger and higher z-index

Tags: html, css, image, layout, flexbox

I am trying to achieve this

[image: Three images arranged with a single center one more prominant and central]

Image 1 and 3 would be slightly hidden behind image 2.

I have this html

```
<div class="imageBanner">
           <div class="imageLeft">
              <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
           </div>
           <div class="imageCentre">
              <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
           </div>
           <div class="imageRight">
              <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
           </div>
        </div>
```

Simple setup, single containing div with three sub divs each holding an image (identical native size).

Current CSS

```
    .imageBanner {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      width:100%;
      max-width: 1024px;}

   .imageLeft img{
    max-width: 60%;
}

.imageCentre {
    z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
}

.imageCentre img{
    width: 100%;
}

.imageRight img{
    max-width: 60%;
}
```

So what I have done is aligned the images along the x axis using flex. I have then given the center image a position of absolute so that the z-index is taken into account. However this is where I run into the issue and the images are not laying out like the above example.

Here is a example if it helps

```css
.imageBanner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
}

.imageLeft img{
    max-width: 60%;
}

.imageCentre {
    z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
}

.imageCentre img{
    width: 100%;
}

.imageRight img{
    max-width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageBanner">
               <div class="imageLeft">
                  <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
               </div>
               <div class="imageCentre">
                  <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
               </div>
               <div class="imageRight">
                  <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
               </div>
</div>
```

I feel like I may be close and will keep trying but any help will be great!

Thanks
Tom

Comment: I've answered a similar question. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875381/stacking-some-images/40875682#40875682  . Maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you think about something like this:

```css
.imageBanner {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
}

.imageLeft {
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
   z-index: -1;
}

.imageCentre {
    width: 60%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.imageRight {
  width: 40%;
 display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
   z-index: -1;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageBanner">
           <div class="imageLeft">
              <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
           </div>
           <div class="imageCentre">
              <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
           </div>
           <div class="imageRight">
              <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
           </div>
        </div>
```

Left image's left indent you can set by change `left:` attribute, and right image's right indent change `right:`

Comment: This looks promising, the only thing I just noticed is that if we go past the max-width of 1024px the layout seems to break. Anyway we can stop it from resizing further once it get to this size?

Comment: have added `position: relative; margin: 0 auto;` to parent div. Look at snippet

Comment: thanks for coming back to me, I did manage to get to this stage and it seems to be working now, have accepted this as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
     .imageBanner {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      width:100%;
      max-width: 1024px;}

img {
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
 .imageBanner {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      width:100%;
      max-width: 1024px;}

img {
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.imageCentre {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 900;
}

.imageLeft {
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
}

.imageRight {
  position: relative;
  right: 5%;
}
.imageCentre {
  width: 100%;
}
```

as shown in the  fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fce2n85s/1/

Comment: This looks good as well, but once the screen size goes below 1020px the middle image seems to scale down much faster than the outer two images.

Answer (score 0):

nothing change in your code just add this css in your css code. if it's works answer me !

```
.imageBanner img { 
    border:solid 5px #000
}
.imageLeft {
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:-5px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.imageBanner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 1024px;
}

.imageLeft img{
    max-width: 60%;
}

.imageCentre {
    z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
}

.imageCentre img{
    width: 100%;
}

.imageRight img{
    max-width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageBanner">
               <div class="imageLeft">
                  <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
               </div>
               <div class="imageCentre">
                  <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
               </div>
               <div class="imageRight">
                  <img src="https://unsplash.it/600/400/">
               </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).