# Image with opacity layers vertically in html and css

Tags: html, css

I tried create a view something like following image in css but no useful result using before .

[image: check image]

my CSS codes :

```
 .geo-login-left{
    background-color: #7199bd;
    background-image: url(../img/home-bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
   }

 .geo-login-left:before{
   background-image: url(../images/logo-white.jpg);
   margin-top: 5px;
   content : "";
   opacity: 0.3;
   }

 .geo-login-left:after{
  background-image: url(../images/logo-white.jpg);
  content : "";
  }
```

Comment: can you please share a fiddle for this

Comment: here is solution of similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048201/3-image-layout-center-image-larger-and-higher-z-index/41048391#41048391. you can just reorder images and paly with z-indexes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/95h82gha/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One without images would be like:

```css
body {
  background-color: #0074D9;
}

.box {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  padding: 2em;
  position: relative;
  width: 24em;
}
.box:before, .box:after {
  background: inherit;
  border-top-left-radius: inherit;
  border-top-right-radius: inherit;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
.box:before {
  height: 1em;
  top: -1em;
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
}
.box:after {
  height: 2em;
  top: -2em;
  width: calc(100% - 4em);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Block
</div>
```